# â€“ like symbols when using text editor

Tags: php, sql

When I used text editors to insert text into database, symbols like   `- , '`   etc get converted to  `â€“` like symbols. How can I avoid these symbols?

Comment: Sounds like a difference in encodings?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please read the [FAQ] before too long.  You will need to provide more information about what you mean.  As Mike suggested, there is probably a problem with the encodings, but it is hard to see what can be going wrong.  The 'symbols like' list appear to be ordinary ASCII codes; the 'converted to' symbols are UTF8 when I copy them, and occupy 8 bytes (2 bytes, 3 bytes and 3 bytes).  You may need to specify your platform (Windows, Unix), editor (`vim`, `emacs`, MS Word), and code sets.  And describe how you're getting the data into PHP, and which SQL DBMS you're using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set names to UTF8 before inserting into your database.

```
SET NAMES utf8
```

It sounds like your connection is using latin1 encoding. I struggled with the same thing for months.

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?103,46870,47245

Answer (score 0):

Check the encoding (collation) used on the database. Try changing it to `utf8_general_ci` or the equivalent choice on the Database you are using.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set encoding to utf8 using method [mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-set-charset.php)

```
<?php
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'user', 'password');
mysql_set_charset('utf8',$link);
$db_selected = mysql_select_db('your_db_name', $link); 
?>
```

And then the usual stuff you do with your connection